# context.addMessage not working for a fileupload component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to display a Message in the uploadListner of a fileUpload component.How ever it is not displaying any message at all.Below is the code snippet that I am using.

```
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Please remove special charecters from the File Name.        ",
                "");
        context.addMessage(null, msg);
```

I tried the same thing in p:commandButton , it is working correctly.
This is the XHTML part of the snippet.

Comment: can i see your <h:message> tag ?

Comment: Hi, I am not using any h:messages tag.This is the XHTML part:    <p:fileUpload id="deployWar" fileUploadListener="#{systemUpdateBean.handleFileUpload}" update=":buddhiEdgeSystemUpdateServiceForm">

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong. you can't display error messages without using h:message tag.

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" actionListener="#{systemUpdateBean.savePerson}"   
            ajax="false" /> The code snippet in the question works fine for me if using it for a command button.I am not using any h:message at all.

Comment: then you must have a h:messageS element? post your xhtml (the whole file)

Comment: you need the h:message for you to put it the message there.
of course your snippet works.. but you can't display the message because you have no h:message tag.
to be sure .. post your xhtml too ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a `<h:messages>`, `<p:messages>` or `<p:growl>` component in the view in order to display messages. Given that you're using `null` client ID in `FacesContext#addMessage()`, you probably intend to display a global message, in that case you could add a `globalOnly="true"` attribute to the aforementioned message components to filter global messages only.

Further, if you're sending an ajax request, you should also not forget to ajax-update the message component by specifing the client ID of the message component in the `update` attribute of the `<p:fileUpload>`.

E.g.

```
<p:fileUpload ... update="messages" />
...
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

Or, if you're using the PrimeFaces equivalent, you could also use `autoUpdate="true"` instead:

```
<p:fileUpload ... />
...
<p:messages globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" />
```